# Write optimized, lock free, log structure index?

Tags: database, indexing, data-structures, azure-cosmosdb

Azure's DocumentDB has a write optimized JSON datastore with automatic indexing of records.  Are there good resources to read about how this is achieved?  Is this well documented in the academic database literature?

DocumentDB describes the indexing policy as:

> Automatic indexing of documents is enabled by write optimized, lock free, and log structured index maintenance techniques. DocumentDB supports a sustained volume of fast writes while still serving consistent queries.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-indexing-policies/

It is also claimed that this index typically requires 2-20% of the size of the main table:

> Based production usage in consumer scale first party applications using DocumentDB, the typical index overhead is between 2-20%. The indexing technology used by DocumentDB ensures that regardless of the values of the properties, the index overhead does not exceed more than 80% of the size of the documents with default settings.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-manage/#IndexOverhead

Are there any papers that describe how to implement this sort of indexing scheme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no paper, yet. 
A paper describing the internals of our indexing has been drafted and is undergoing final reviews. 
We expect to publish this as soon as it is final.

Comment: Has this paper been published now?